# read.csv Fails Due to Rows With A Trailing Comma

Tags: r, read.csv

I am reading from an API into a CSV file.
I then use R to perform calculations on that data. I am using `read.csv` to read the data into R.

In a few cases, the last column of a row has a blank value so the row ends in a comma.

This causes `read.csv` to fail.

Short of writing a script to fix the file, is there any way to read the CSV with a row or rows ending with a trailing comma?

Comment: `read.csv` defaults to `fill = TRUE`, so if the number of commas is the same in all rows, that error shouldn't happen. (I have just checked it, once again, and rows ending in a comma were read in correctly, no errors). Are you sure there's nothing else that can cause the error? And what is the error message?

Comment: Hi Rui. The error is:

Comment: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : more columns than column names

Comment: This error is telling you that you have fewer column names in the first row of the data  than columns of data. You really need to show use the actual R commands you used. You may need to use `skip=1, header=FALSE` and then add the column names after reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

I see what I did wrong. Some of my CSV fields are enclosed in double quotes, however I failed to define a quote character in my read.csv statement.

Here is my corrected statement:

MyData <<- read.csv(file=“myfile.csv”, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=“,”, quote=“\””)

Note that the quote parameter is escaped with a backslash.

Thanks to all.